# Skip part of URL

Tags: htaccess, url, xampp

I have a server running on XAMPP in LAN.

In htdocs I've created subfolder called 'apps' (it's because I'm using one CodeIgniter's files to multiple webpages).

Now, when somenone want to visit a webpage, must visit: `http://myserver/apps/app_name`.

Is it possible with *.htaccess* (or else) to skip that `/apps/` part? `http://myserver/app_name` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Activate `mod_rewrite`, and put this in a .htaccess file or a `<Directory>` directive:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^apps/
RewriteRule (.*) apps/$1
```

What it does:

The first three lines check if the requested URI refers to an actually existing file, directory or link, in order to make sure that e.g. an `index.html` at top level is still delivered if requested.

The fourth line makes sure that the user has not already requested an URI in the `apps/` subpath.

If the requested URI is not an existing file, directory or link and does not start with `apps/`, the path of the URL is taken and `apps/` is prepended. This only happens internally.

Comment: thanks for your help. I have last one questions. How to hide that /app/ part from url?

Comment: It should not be visible, if you just enter `http://yoursite.com/foobar`, as the rewriting to `http://yoursite.com/apps/foobar` is only done internally. If you want to redirect all paths starting with `apps/` to strip that part, this rule should do, if placed before the other ones: `RewriteRule ^apps/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,QSA,L]`. It does a 301-redirect, you can change the http status code by changing the `R=301`. The QSA appends any parameters the original URL had to the new URL, and the L stops further rewriting the request after that rule in order to send out the redirect to the browser.